# Magento 2 - How can I write query in Magento

Tags: database, magento2.3, factory

I have a SQL query that joins two tables.

> SELECT ot.name, org.name from ayakil_organization as org INNER JOIN
>   ayakil_organization_type as ot ON org.type_id = ot.type_id ORDER BY
>   ot.name ASC

Here **ayakil_organization**, **ayakil_organization_type** are two tables.

my resolver class is like below.

```
$collection = $this->_organizationFactory->create()->getCollection();
$collection->getCollection()->getSelect()
            ->join(
                ['ot' => 'e25_organization_type'],
                'main_table.type_id = ot.type_id',
                array("*")
            )
            ->setOrder('ot.name','ASC');
```

If i use the collection query like this, i am getting an error.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any model files for **ayakil_organization** this table ?

Comment: yes, both tables are handles by two different modules, each tables have its own models and factory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this..

```
$this->ayakilOrganizationModel
    ->getCollection()
    ->getSelect()
    ->join(
        ['ot' => 'ayakil_organization_type'],
        'main_table.type_id = ot.type_id',
        array("*")
    )
    ->setOrder('ot.name','ASC');
```

This will return same query which you want.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thank you, i check and accept the answer

Comment: Okay and let me know if you have any query there then :)

Comment: i am using factory method to get the data like this.
$collection = $this->_organizationFactory->create()->getCollection(); Can i used model also with that?

Comment: You can use Factory there.

Comment: thanks, I will check :)

Comment: hi i cannot use factory method.i am getting an error,can you please help me?

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: my code is not moved after these lines.no errors specifically.

Comment: Can you please echo your query like **echo $collection->getSelect()** and check what you're getting there ?