# How to join tables and retrive data

Tags: magento2, database, frontend, join-table

I want to join `entity_id` column from `customer_entity` table with `customer_id` from `new_info` table and want to get `department` column value of given customer.

Comment: do u want to show in an admin grid or want to get a collection?

Comment: No, Not in admin grid. I just want collection.

Comment: Please check this answer, It may be help you.. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295415/magento-2-how-can-i-write-query-in-magento/295417#295417

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to get the department column value from your custom table on basis of customer entity_id field.

```
protected $_customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    ...
) {
   $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

public function yourfunctionname(){

   $customersCollection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $customersCollection->getSelect()
                            ->joinLeft(['ni' => 'new_info'], 'ni.customer_id = e.entity_id', ['department' => 'ni.department']);

   return $customersCollection;
}
```

**In above code:**

ni = your custom table alias name and, new_info = your custom table name

Hope this solution will help you!